# Creating a spatial join for longitude/latitude data to areas on a base map

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, latitude-longitude, spatial-join

I have three different sets of data: The basemap (local authority wards), crime (recorded through longitude and latitude), population (recorded by local authority ward). I have already mapped the crime data onto the base map through longitude and latitude. I would now like to spatially link the crime data to each ward, so I have a number of crime recorded for each ward. I would then like to add the population data to this so I have population per ward and can calculate crime recorded per population.

I have attempted to do "Join attributes by location" and attempting to join the crime data to the basemap, but this has not worked. I get an error that states that my basemap has "invalid geometry"

Answer (score 1):

Try using the **Fix Geometries** tool on your basemap layer.  The tool is located within in the Processing Toolbox.